# php not getting data from android

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send the data in json format from android to a php webservice.
But I the webservice in not getting anything in its response.
What I tried:

```
public void postLatLong (double lat, double lon) throws MalformedURLException {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://server/path/index.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outwriter);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("lat", lat);
        json.put("lon", lon);
        Log.d("JSONString",json.toString());
        writer.write(json.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inreader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inreader);
        Log.d("Response",reader.readLine());
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("posting Error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("JSONException", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting the respons.
There is no error logs shown, the json is ok, I can watch it in logs .But, when I check the webservice log, there is nothing in POST request.

Comment: Please include error messages / stack trace / event log information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your PHP code/configuration header is set or not if not then set

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
```

It will helpful to you.